# TLS handshake hostname mismatch even when SNI matches with server-certificate subject name

Tags: tls1.2, x509

I encounter a hostname mismatch error at the client side in the server certificate verification step:- "Verify return code: 62 (hostname mismatch)".

But am able to see that hostname sent in Client-hello in SNI extension is matching with server-certificate's Subject name(Common Name):-

> SNI extension in client-hello;-
>
> ```
>     extension_type=server_name(0), length=18
>       0000 - 00 10 00 00 0d 54 4c 53-2d 55 6e 69 74 2d 54   .....TLS-Unit-T
>       000f - 65 73 74                                       est
>     extension_type=ec_point_formats(11), length=4
> ```
>
> Server-certificate common-name:-
>
> ```
>     Subject: C = IN, ST = KA, L = Bangalore, O = Cisco, CN = TLS-Unit-Test
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject field is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations). Proper TLS clients do not look in this field at all, they examine SAN extension instead. SAN extension must contain all domain names the certificate is valid for.